# What is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax

```
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
     CHECKPOINT;
    DELETE TOP (300000)
      FROM [dbo].[Event] AS E
     INNER JOIN #tempEvents AS TE
        ON E.[EventID] = TE.[EventID]
END
```

For starters, I get:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`

So, I remove this and replace with the aliases with full table names, which gives me:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.`

I found this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12953/sql-drive-getting-full-delete-millions-of-rows) which is where I found out about doing an `INNER JOIN`, but SQL Server isn't parsing this correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
     CHECKPOINT;
    DELETE TOP (300000) E
      FROM [dbo].[Event] AS E
     INNER JOIN #tempEvents AS TE
        ON E.[EventID] = TE.[EventID]
END
```

you missed the tablename/alias after the top statement.